# How to know the paramenter stored in excel exported from dataset in anylogic

Tags: dataset, anylogic

I succeeded duplicate the dataset-NumberofUsers-from Anylogic to excel when I did a parameter variation experiment, but I can only see the number of users and don't know what kind of parameters resulted in those results. Where can I find parameter data? Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way you do it for the NumberofUsers. Create a dataset for each parameter and each time you add a value to NumberofUsers, repeat the same code for the ParameterDataset to the value of the parameter being tested. In the end, export all datasets to excel the same way you are currently exporting your dataset. You will have two datasets next to each other, one with the parameter being tested, the other with the results.

Comment: Thank you so much! There is another little question. Does the dataset layout according to the sequence that I typed in the code? I mean like the following code, in Excel the first column is Nuser, the second is Adeff, the third Adoption? Thank you:)
plot.addDataSet(root.NUserDS);
plot.addDataSet(root.Adeff);
plot.addDataSet(root.Adoption);

Comment: Not sure I understand, can you please rephrase?